# jquery mobile and mobiscroll it appears behind of jquery mobile popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

I am working with Jquery mobile and mobiscroll, I am using a popup with not-modal, to call a mobiscroll datetime, when I call a mobiscrooll from popup is positioned behind of jquery mobile popup. I am triying to get it ahead, but I can't.  I try opcion display Controls the positioning of the scroller but it doesn't work. Any suggestions or recomendation. Apreciate your help.

```
'modal' - Scroller appears as a popup at the center of the viewport.
'inline' - If called on div element, scroller is placed inside the div (overwriting existing content), otherwise is placed after the original element.
'bubble' - Scroller appears as a bubble positioned to the element defined by the 'anchor' setting. By default the anchor is the original element.
'top' - Scroller appears docked to the top of the viewport.
'bottom' - Scroller appears docked to the bottom of the viewport.
```

[image]

My code here

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>

         <h1>Header</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content</div> <a href="#AddingDialog" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

    <div
    data-role="popup" id="AddingDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:500px;" data-position-to="window" class="ui-corner-all">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
             <h1>Entre Fechas:</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">

            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <input  name="desde" id="desde" placeholder="Fecha Desde:" maxlength="100"  />
                <input  name="hasta" id="hasta" placeholder="Fecha Hasta:" maxlength="100"  />

            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="a"><font color="white"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></font></i></a>

                </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="a" data-transition="flow"id="doAddItem"><font color="white"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></font></i></a>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
     <h4>Footer</h4>

</div>
</div>
```

my js

```
$('#desde, #hasta').mobiscroll().datetime({
    //minDate: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()),
    theme: 'jqm',
    display: 'modal',
    animate: 'pop',
    //mode: 'mixed',
    // 2013-03-15 11:26:17
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    timeFormat: 'HH:ii:ss',
    timeWheels: 'HHii',
    lang: 'es'
});
```

css

```
<style type="text/css">
#AddingDialog-screen {
    display: none;
}
        </style>
```

Comment: Change the z-index of the mobiscroll div in css to a higher value.

Comment: could you give me a example ? thank you

Comment: I change in css a values and it doesn't work

Comment: any solutions to this? i'm facing the same issue. :/